# How do we generate Key Id that is used as a parameter for SFTP connection from NetSuite?

Tags: connection, sftp, suitescript, required

I have followed the suite article in Netsuite https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/51362 to establish a connection between Netsuite and SFTP which has three parameters (KeyId,passwordGuid, and secret) among which two of them become optional when the third one is selected I would like to know how could we generate key Id in Netsuite and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In netsuite help there is a complete example on how to connect netsuite with sftp

https://tstdrv1229883.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4855401415.html

hope this might help